# .net Core 2.2 EF: SaveChangesAsync() setting unrelated columns to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.2 application.  I've written a couple of new Razor pages to update some new data to an existing model.

The problem is that when I "submit" my form and call SaveChangesAsync(), it updates the fields I've changed ... and it *ERASES* most of the other fields in the record.

The model has 40 or 50 properties; I'm only trying to update 3 or 4 of them.

But *EVERYTHING* except "ID" and the fields in my form are getting set to "null" by the update.

Q: Any idea what I'm missing?

```
public class EditPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Project.Models.MyContext _context;

    [BindProperty]
    public MyModel MyRecord { get; set; }

    public EditPageModel(Project.Models.MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        // <= This is OK...

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        MyRecord = await _context.MyModel.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        // <= This is OK, too: I call "return Page()" and everything looks fine...

    public async Task<IActionResult>OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        // Update DB
        _context.Attach(MyRecord).State = EntityState.Modified;
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();  
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            // No exceptions, no errors or warnings: Never get here...
            ...
        }
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
```

Comment: What does `MyRecord` look like at the begining of the `onPostAsync` method? Can you show us your client code?

Comment: Most of the fields in "MyRecord" were null, which makes perfect sense: if the view doesn't need to display the data, EF shouldn't have to fetch it. But why isn't EF smart enough not to update those fields that it didn't fetch???

Comment: But you told EF to set those fields as null in your code. You did that when you passed in the model with null values from the client. That's how model binding works. Fetch the entity from the DB only when you need to update and only update those 3 fields and call SaveChanges(). don't pass it around like that, you will get unexpected results. In this case the model binding is an extra layer you have to consider with updating your Entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

Option 1: add hidden fields for each and every property in your model that don't need to be changed.

Option 2: load record from database, map properties from model to the db object and save changes, without attaching the binding model to the context.

Comment: PS: you could try this: https://www.endyourif.com/updating-specific-fields-using-entity-framework/. Honestly don't know if it works with ef core too, but it might.

Comment: Yup - you're absolutely correct. Most of the fields in "MyRecord" were null, which makes perfect sense: if the view doesn't need to display the data, EF shouldn't have to fetch it.  But why isn't EF smart enough not to update those fields that it didn't fetch???  Anyway, `dbEntry.Property(includeProperty).IsModified = true;` worked like a charm :)  Thank you :)

Comment: Basically when you `_context.Attach(MyRecord).State = EntityState.Modified;` you are telling EF   *"The whole object is changed"*, so EF sends all the fields in the UPDATE statement. Instead, by querying first for the object, you get a proxy class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, that allows DbContext change tracker to know what is changed in each entity, also keeping track of old and new values.